# Refresh Firebase token with Angular when token expired

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, token

I'm making a site with Angular, i implemented the Firebase SDK to authenticate with its token via email/password.

The goal is to have a new token automatically once the user closes the site and reopens it after a week, but I have no idea what function to implement and how.

I tried to get the token and refresh the token (and i succeeded), but i don't know what function to use to request a new token once it expired. I can't understand from the Firebase documentation. can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
After first time user login, i save token and refresh token then in app component (in constructor) i create a method where i check if i have refresh token in local storage. if there is a refresh token then I call a Firebase API which returns me the new token and the new refresh token.
Here is an example of the method:

```
//the method
if (localStorage.getItem("refreshToken") != null) {
      console.log("refresh token not null");
      var request = {
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        refresh_token: localStorage.getItem("refreshToken")
      };
      console.log("request...");
      this.http.post<RefreshTokenResponse>("https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=[YOUR_KEY]", request)
        .subscribe(x => {
          console.log(x.access_token);
          localStorage.setItem("token", x.access_token)
          console.log(x.refresh_token);
          localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", x.refresh_token);
        });
    }

export interface RefreshTokenResponse{
    access_token:string,
    refresh_token:string
}

export interface RefreshTokenRequest{
    grant_type: string;
    refresh_token:string;
}
```